# How do I extract all embedded objects (multiple types) in a word .docx and save them into a folder?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word .docx with ~50 embedded objects. I would like all of them saved into a folder with the correct file names. Because I want the names correct, I don't want to do the .zip approach available online. The embedded objects range from PowerPoints,  to Excel Docs, to Emails, to PDFs, and more.

I have tried the VBA solutions on 1-2 dozen sites online, but none of them are working. The one that seems to be working best is the one on this website: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/5920f36f-5338-44ee-881f-5c9777a65e59/copy-embedded-objects-through-vba?forum=exceldev

The code I am using is seen below. When I run it, a box pops up asking me to select a folder. I select the folder containing (only) my .docx file. It creates a folder inside the chosen folder called "Embedded", but it does not fill up with anything. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

```
Sub ExtractEmbeddedObjects()
' The following macro extracts the embedded objects from all docx & docm files in that folder and outputs them
' to a new 'Embedded' folder in that folder. Each output file's name is prefixed with the parent
' document's name.
'
'Note: The macro only processes docx & docm files - doc files can't be processed this way (though they could be converted to the docx format for processing).
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim SBar As Boolean           ' Status Bar flag
Dim StrInFold As String, StrOutFold As String, StrTmpFold As String
Dim StrDocFile As String, StrZipFile As String, Obj_App As Object, i As Long
Dim StrFile As String, StrFileList As String, StrEmbedFile As String, j As Long
StrInFold = GetFolder
If StrInFold = "" Then Exit Sub
' Store current Status Bar status, then switch on
SBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
StrOutFold = StrInFold & "\Embedded"
StrTmpFold = StrInFold & "\Tmp"
'Test for existing tmp & output folders, create they if they don't already exist
If Dir(StrTmpFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir StrTmpFold
If Dir(StrOutFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir StrOutFold
'Create a Shell App for accessing the zip archives
Set Obj_App = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'Look for docx files to process
StrFile = Dir(StrInFold & "\*.doc?", vbNormal)
'Build the file list
While StrFile <> ""
  StrFileList = StrFileList & "|" & StrFile
  StrFile = Dir()
Wend
'process the file list
j = UBound(Split(StrFileList, "|"))
For i = 1 To j
  'ID the document to process
  StrDocFile = StrInFold & "\" & Split(StrFileList, "|")(i)
  ' Report progress on Status Bar.
  Application.StatusBar = "Processing file " & i & " of " & j & ": " & StrDocFile
  'Define the zip name
  StrZipFile = Split(StrDocFile, ".")(0) & ".zip"
  'In case the file is in use or zip file has no media
  On Error Resume Next
  'Create the zip file, by simply copying to a new file with a zip extension
  FileCopy StrDocFile, StrZipFile
  'Extract the zip archive's media files to the temporary folder
  Obj_App.NameSpace(StrTmpFold & "\").CopyHere Obj_App.NameSpace(StrZipFile & "\word\embeddings\").Items
  'Delete the zip file - the loop takes care of timing issues
  Do While Dir(StrZipFile) <> ""
    Kill StrZipFile
  Loop
  'Restore error trapping
  On Error GoTo 0
  'Get the temporary folder's file listing
  StrEmbedFile = Dir(StrTmpFold & "\*.*", vbNormal)
  'Process the temporary folder's files
  While StrEmbedFile <> ""
    'Copy the file to the output folder, prefixed with the source file's name
    FileCopy StrTmpFold & "\" & StrEmbedFile, StrOutFold & "\" & Split(Split(StrFileList, "|")(i), ".")(0) & StrEmbedFile
    'Delete the media file
    Kill StrTmpFold & "\" & StrEmbedFile
    'Get the next media file
    StrEmbedFile = Dir()
  Wend
Next
'Delete the temporary folder
RmDir StrTmpFold
' Clear the Status Bar
Application.StatusBar = False
' Restore original Status Bar status
Application.DisplayStatusBar = SBar
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Embedded objects are renamed and the old names discarded, so you're not getting that information back. Only linked objects retain the original file name and path.

Comment: Can you help me understand what you mean? Are you saying that there is no way to get embedded objects?

Comment: Is the .docx open when you run the code (perhaps you put the code in the .docx - it only needs to become a .docm when you save it) ? If so, the file will be open and the line ` FileCopy StrDocFile, StrZipFile` will throw error 70. Except it won't, because you have `On Error Resume Next` before it. So no .zip is created, nothing is copied into `\Tmp`, and no files are generated, and no error will be reported.

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve the objects. No, you can't get the original names for them.

Answer (score 0):

The work app which I used is: O365.
Right click the embedded file icon (worksheet)
》worksheet object 》 convert
》 change Icon
》 in the "Caption", we can see the object file name.
But after search all the file in the *.docx 》*.zip extract files in npp.
I cannot find any information relative with above mention file name.
So I think the original object file name is still in the *.docx,
but don't know where to get it.